# sprite anchor point for rotateToAngle

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In sprite kit, how do I rotate a sprite from a position other than its center? does changing its anchor point have anything to do with this?

I'm using an action to perform the rotation:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(1, duration: 0.1, shortestUnitArc: true)
node.runAction(action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to change the `anchorPoint`. The x and y of the `anchorPoint` can vary from `0` to `1`, this image from [Working With Sprites](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html) should help explain:

[image]

Comment: question for you, when I'm changing the anchor point, the physics body is appearing a bit off. Its appearing a little higher than the actual sprite. Any idea why this is happening

Comment: Does the amount it's off by relate to the new `anchorPoint`? You could use `skView.showsPhysics = true` to check the position of the physics body.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I had to change with the position of the node itself, and things worked out. Thanks for the tip on the showPhysics property too!